# What does the GraphLayout -> "SpectralEmbedding" option do (mean) when displaying a graph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, implementation-details

I have some relational data represented as a graph. As such some of the relational properties can be recognized. When I use the GraphLayout -> "SpectralEmbedding" option a very nice and sharply ordered graph is displayed. But what does it mean? What is GraphLayout -> "SpectralEmbedding" doing?

Comment: [GraphLayout  >> Scope >> VertexLayout  >> SpectralEmbedding](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GraphLayout.html) : _Place vertices so the weighted sum of squares of mutual distances is minimized._

Comment: @kglr - I read that too, but I can't figure out how to show it.  If you try different embeddings in `(EuclideanDistance @@@ 
  Partition[GraphEmbedding@PathGraph[Range[20], GraphLayout -> XXX], 
   2, 1])^2` it doesn't show that "SpectralEmbedding" minimizes the distances.

Comment: I assume [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_layout) and its attached references are relevant.

Comment: I think this is related to spectral community detection methods, which first embed the graph in space this way, then do a clustering on the vertex coordinates.  You can read e.g. here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1307.7729v1.pdf

Comment: Section 5 of [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.camwa.2004.08.015) (linked in the Wiki page given by @Rahul) seems to tell me that this is the method being referred to.

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19315/what-algorithm-is-mathematica-9-using-for-spectralembedding-of-graphs